# When should I use "caution" instead of "warning" and vice versa?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can you tell me in which context I should use *caution* and *warning*?

*Caution* seems more formal, and more serious than *warning*. *Caution* can imply *fatal*, while *warning* refers to errors or mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caution seems more formal, and more serious than warning.

Actually, in some contexts, the opposite is true. In the US, there is an ANSI standard for safety signage (and I believe a corresponding ISO standard) that specifies how these words are used in signs in the workplace:

> Warning—Indicate a potentially hazardous situation which, if not avoided, could result in death or serious injury.
>
> Caution—Indicate a potentially hazardous situation which, if not avoided, may result in minor or moderate injury. Caution may also be used to alert against unsafe practices.

([source](http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/static/safety-sign-marking-requirements-201.html))

For example,

[image] [image]

Comment: @truongha, Thanks for the accept. But be aware this isn't a complete answer, just a focus on one particular use of these words. In general conversation, they are more-or-less the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning** is an explanation about a thing or an act at a particular place where a person might accidentally harm his/herself. It is a symbol or a message conveyed to the person in a place where a factor of risk occurs.

**Caution** maybe the procedures to note something before touching or acting on a thing or product.

Answer (score 1):

When *warning* means "a statement telling somebody that they will be punished if they continue to behave in a particular way," it is synonym with *caution*. Two of the meanings of *caution* are:

- A warning that is given by the police to somebody who has committed a crime that is not too serious (British English)
- A warning or a piece of advice about a possible danger or risk (Formal)

*Caution* also means "care that you take in order to avoid danger or mistakes; not taking any risks." In that case, you cannot replace it with *warning*.

> *** Statistics should be treated with warning.